# Use wget as user agent

Tags: ubuntu, wget, http-status-code-403

How can I download a text file via commandline without a 403, using wget?
I am setting a user-agent but still getting 403:

**The command**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-71:~/Downloads$ wget -O jane-austen.txt  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-0.txt"
```

**Output**

```
--2017-02-07 21:10:58--  http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-0.txt
Resolving www.gutenberg.org (www.gutenberg.org)... 152.19.134.47, 2610:28:3090:3000:0:bad:cafe:47
Connecting to www.gutenberg.org (www.gutenberg.org)|152.19.134.47|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-02-07 21:11:06 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: I don't think that's about the user agent.  It just means that text isn't available to you.  You'll need to research the rules.  FWIW, the wget worked for me without any special headers.

Comment: me too, it works with : `wget -O jane-austen.txt  "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1342/1342-0.txt"` GNU Wget 1.19 built on linux-gnu.

Comment: User Agent doesn't magically turn 403s into 200s, haha. But some insight into why it might be happening: on typing the same URL into my browser, I was redirected to a 'Welcome, Stranger' page. Subsequent visits correctly went to the right file. You might want to try enabling a session or just plain visiting the file on your browser once to make sure they cache your IP.

Comment: @Akshat: interesting behaviour, in this case, do we need to make twice a wget?

Comment: @Tom Kuschel - That depends on Gutenberg's website and its behaviour handling requests. It might not be a bad idea to just try visiting the file twice.